# How to include Groovy 2.0 in a deployed Grails 2.1.0 app?

Tags: grails, deployment, groovy, war

I've updated my dev box to Grails 2.1.0 and Groovy 2.0 (Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit, STS 2.9).

After migrating my apps from 2.0 to 2.1.0, I've noticed that the WAR file still included the groovy-all Groovy 1.8.6 jar.

My question is:

- is possible (or advisable) to make Grails include the Groovy 2.0 Jar?
- does it make sense to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Grails 2.1 is based on Groovy 1.8, Grails 2.2 uses Groovy 2.0, Grails 2.3 uses Groovy 2.1. Changes of Groovy version in the past have necessitated changes to the Grails core code, so it's certainly not advisable (and probably not possible) to use a version of Groovy other than the one the particular Grails release was built against.

Comment: + infinity on this one. As @Ian-Roberts mentions don't do it :)